# Passando dados de um txt para outro txt

Tags: java, arquivo

Tenho um ficheiro `.txt` com três nomes separados por virgula, no caso:

**teste.txt**

```
 João,Maria,José
```

Na minha classe eu pego o arquivo e passo para um `array`, separando por vírgula:

```
String nomeArquivo="teste.txt";
String nomeArquivoGerado="gerado.txt";
String linha = "";
String linha2[];

try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(nomeArquivo);
    BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(reader);
    linha=leitor.readLine();
    linha2=linha.split(",");
```

Eu quero pegar algumas posições do `array` e salvar em outro `.txt` que seria o `gerado.txt` (vazio).

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(nomeArquivoGerado);
PrintWriter gravarArquivo = new PrintWriter(nomeArquivoGerado);
gravarArquivo.printf(linha2[0]).print(linha2[1]);
writer.close();
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem dois objetos referenciando um mesmo arquivo, não existe problemas técnicos nisso, mas da forma que está no seu código além de desnecessário te levou a cometer um erro de lógica pois você tenta escrever através do objeto do PrintWriter mas você não dá *flush* nele (o *flush* faz com que todas as informações que estão no *buffer* sejam efetivamente escritas no seu arquivo).

O método `close()` chama o método `flush()` antes de efetivamente fechar o recurso, entretanto você está chamando o método `close()` no seu **outro** objeto, o objeto que você não inseriu nenhuma informação, por isso seu arquivo fica vazio ao final da execução do seu programa. Portanto, a solução é você chamar o método `close()` (ou pode chamar também o método `flush()`) no **mesmo** objeto que você escrever.

As diferenças entre FileWriter e PrintWriter são poucas, basicamente o PrintWriter possui alguns métodos que o FileWriter não possui, como o `print()` e o `println()`. Ambos possuem os métodos `write()` e `append()`. Apenas escolha um dos dois e apague o outro. Independente de qual classe optar por trabalhar, faça o *flush* após inserir as informações nele.